# Add validation rule to a class without using the form validation?

Tags: jquery, validation

I want to validate elements with class X using jQuery
I looked on net I found just the validation form and I don't want to use it
is there another solution?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this [plugin to validate a form](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) but it only validates `input`s where you add the required classes, for example :

```
<input value="someone@nowhere.com" class="validate[required,custom[email]]" type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<input value="2010-12-01" class="validate[required,custom[date]]" type="text" name="date" id="date" />
<input value="too many spaces obviously" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber]]" type="text" name="special" id="special" />
```

the first `input` would require (class = `validate[required,custom[email]]`) a valid email to be entered. The second a valid date (class= `validate[required,custom[date]]`) and the third only letters or numbers (class = `validate[required,custom[onlyLetterNumber]]`)

Comment: Thanks ManseUK just a question for email and onlyLetterNumber I use functions?

Comment: @Yasminette nope - they are pre-built in functions ... see the plugin page i linked too - you can write your own functions should you require